# If not do nothing pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to do a if not condition but I'm missing something here :)

What I want to do is, if the current candle is 2x bigger than the previous candle, do nothing, else the condition is good to go.

```
BodySizeMath = math.abs(close - open) / open

BigerThen = if BodySizeMath *2 > BodySizeMath[1]
    close
else
    open
```

but is clearly not right.

If the condition is on do nothing else active it (not a strategy entry but a condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a `bool` variable.

```
BigerThen = (BodySizeMath *2 > BodySizeMath[1])
```

`BigerThen` here will be `true` if the curent candle is 2x biger then the previous candle and `false` otherwise.

So you can use it in your conditional checks.

```
if (BigerThen)
    // Do whatever you want to do
```

## Edit:

If you don't want to do something when your condition is `true`, you just use it with the `not` operator.

Say you have multiple conditions to enter a long position. And you don't want to enter this trade when the current candle is 2x bigger then the previous candle.

Then you can do:

```
long_cond = cond_1 and cond_2 and not BigerThen

if (long_cond)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

In this case, it will only enter a trade if the current candle is **NOT** 2x bigger then the previous one **AND** rest of your conditions are satisfied.

Comment: thanks for you time :) but what if, what i want is Not to activate the trade if current candle is 2x bigger than the previous candle and otherwise the trade can start (if the rest of the condition or meets). literally write would be: if candel is 2x bigger then previous, the trade condition is not meet other wise you can activate the deal

Comment: HO ! THAT SIMPLE ! LOL
thanks a lot for your help  !its working !

Answer (score 0):

You code is strange, you should try this :

```
BodySizeMath = math.abs(close - open)

if BodySizeMath > 2*BodySizeMath[1]
    // Here the currrent candle is 2x bigger the previous candle
    a = 1 // Do nothing
else
    // Here the condition is good to go
    b = 1 // Do something else
```